# FPS for the internet

Tags: video, digital-recording, video-standards

HI I want to know how many FPS I should use for a video for the internet. I guess it depends on where I am going to show it? youtube, vimeo, etc?. if you can, please, give me a list of possibilities, thanks!

Comment: Your framerate firstly depends on your source footage. Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to upload? Is it a screen recording? A video from a DSLR? An animation? Secondly filehosters have limits to their supported frame rates. Vimeo for example [supports 24 (or 23.976), 25 and 30 (or 29.97) frames per second](https://vimeo.com/help/compression).

Comment: thanks for your respond. I have a Camcorder Canon XA10, i am trying to upload a 12 minutes movie i made myself, i guess that's what you called Screen recording, it is not an animation, thanks again

Comment: A screen recording is when you record your computer screen with software to produce a video that can be used in e.g. a tutorial. So you don't have a screen recording. You do have used a camera to record a video. The frame rate (fps) you should chose should be the same as the frame rate of your source footage shot on the Canon XA10. You can run [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) on your video file to see what the frame rate is. Post the results as an edit to your answer so people can help you better.

Answer (score 3):

If your source footage is interlaced, deinterlace it.  If your progressive frame rate is a constant 23.976, 24, 25, 29.97, or 30 fps, then keep the frame rate as it is, unless you require a very low bitrate and want to halve the frame rate.  These are all widely supported frame rates, although other arbitrary frame rates below 30 fps will often work as well.  Many popular devices only claim to support up to 30 fps.  If your source footage has a higher frame rate or you have a variable frame rate, consider converting it to one of these constant frame rates for wider compatibility.  Don't bother if you are submitting to YouTube as they will accept a wide range of frame rates and will re-encode the video for you at various quality levels.

If you are shooting all new footage specifically for the Internet, which will not be combined with existing footage, and you have your choice of frame rate, 30 fps (progressive) is a good and popular choice.  If you will not have any fast motion and want that cinematic look, you may prefer 24 fps.

Comment: Note that Youtube doesn't appear to support over 30 FPS anyway. You can still upload stuff over 60 though, Youtube works it's magic regardless

Answer (score 3):

Most modern codecs will support whatever frame rate you throw at them.  The choice is more of an artistic decision than a technical one.  For the best quality, you should match the frame rate of your source or some even multiple there of.  If you can choose on your source, then choose according to the feel you want.  24(23.976) is more "cinematic" and is what is used in theater films while 30 (29.97) is a little smoother and is what is used by NTSC television (like the US).  48 and 60 are much smoother but also less common.  25 is common in PAL countries.

Comment: Yes, I personally have gotten the best results by keeping the online video in the same frame rate as the original. Instead of trying to tweak the FPS, focus instead on bitrate. Adobe Media Encoder is great for this as it lets you easily specify a variable bitrate, which usually best (exceptions include when you're broadcasting the video from a true streaming server rather than a regular web server).

Comment: P.S. If you don't have Adobe Media Encoder and aren't afraid of the command line, let me know - I can post info on how to accomplish good encoding for the web using ffmpeg.